# Unambiguous and useful time formatting

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone

I can produce a locally-formatted time for visitors:

```
var expires = XXXX
$('#expires').text(new Date(expires).toLocaleTimeString())
```

For example, this produces 12:05:46 PM. However this is ambiguous for the visitor. That is because we have all-too-often become accustomed to websites that improperly calculate timezones.

It would be much better to produce: 12:05:46 PM EDT for me and god-knows-what for other people. Is this possible?

Comment: Then, just pass the proper arguments to **[`.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)** to produce the format you want. (And, by the way, I don't think there's any ambiguity in seeing a time without a time zone attached to it. People just assume all times are local.)

Comment: "EDT" is not a "proper" timezone. Timezone names are not standardised, some names and abbreviations are duplicated and none tell you what the actual offset is (e.g. what is LHST and what is its current offset). If you genuinely want an unambiguous timezone offset, use ±HHmm or ±HH:mm. So instead of "EDT" you'd use -0400 or -04:00.

Answer (score 0):

To get the abbreviation in the output, pass `timeZoneName: 'short'` as one of the options.  This will work in modern browsers that support the ECMAScript Internationalization API (ECMA-402).

```js
var s = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, { timeZoneName: 'short' });
console.log(s);
```

In the above, passing `undefined` for the locale tells the browser to use the users's current locale.  If you wanted a specific locale, such as `en-US`, pass that instead.

You can read about all of the options for `toLocaleTimeString` in [the MDN docs on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

Comment: Setting my timezone to [*Kingston, Norfolk Island*](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/norfolk-island/kingston), Safari, Chrome and Firefox give "GMT+11". I think the OP would have expected something like "NIST" or similar, but I don't know what name or abbreviation is used for that timezone. Even Brisbane, Australia gives "GMT+10" (which I like as it's unambiguous). Setting the language to 'en-us' doesn't change the timezone, it changes the language and format used for the date and time parts. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the world cannot agree on time zone abbreviations.  The abbreviations in this API come from ICU, which come from CLDR.  It has them for Brisbane, but only for `en-AU` and `en-NZ` locales.  For some reason, CLDR thinks time zone abbreviations should only apply in specific regional locales - so you won't see them for `en-US`, or `en-GB`, etc.  In other words, this should work:  `new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-AU', { timeZoneName: 'short', timeZone: 'Australia/Brisbane' })`.  For Norfolk, CLDR has no abbreviation at all - and neither does IANA, so T&D's is made up.

Comment: I guess that's an issue with using language codes as locales, and also assuming everyone in/from a particular locale uses a certain format. To me the two are distinctly different concepts that have somehow become confused as the same thing, or as strongly correlated when they aren't. I might have said that before. ;-)

Comment: Well time zone and locale are unrelated certainly. But I think the combination of language+country+optionals makes a fairly reasonable culture/locale code. IETF language tags for the win. :)